# Editing versus deleting CMakeCache.txt after moving directory

Tags: cmake

If CMake is re-executed after the source directory is moved, an error like this is given:

> CMake Error: The current CMakeCache.txt directory /new-path/CMakeCache.txt is different than the directory /old-path where CMakeCache.txt was created. This may result in binaries being created in the wrong place. If you are not sure, reedit the CMakeCache.txt

What is the best approach to deal with this? It seems that deleting the cache works. Why might I want to edit `CMakeCache.txt`, rather than just delete it?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66480/cmake-error-the-current-directory-is-different-than

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I think your best bet is indeed to delete the cache and re-create it.  In fact, I tend to go further and remove the entire build tree if I need to move the source, but this is probably overkill.

The CMakeCache.txt file *can* be edited via the CMake GUI or by hand if you're sure what you're doing, but I find it's not usually worth the effort compared to re-running cmake from scratch.  I guess if running CMake takes a significant amount of time (e.g. if you use [`ExternalProject_Add`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#module:ExternalProject) which could involve downloading and building a third-party resource), it may be preferable to modify the CMakeCache.txt.

[This article](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/runningcmake.html) provides a bit more detail about the CMakeCache.txt file and editing it.  In particular it says:

> The main reason for editing the cache would be to give CMake the location of a native library such as JPEG, or to stop it from using a native library and use a version of the library in your source tree.
>
> CMake will not alter an existing entry in the cache file itself. If your CMakeLists.txt files change significantly, you will need to remove the relevant entries from the cache file. If you have not already hand-edited the cache file, you could just delete it before re-running CMake.

Comment: I tried clearing my cache with this command: `rm -rf ~/.cache/*` but the error still persists. where am i going wrong?

Comment: The http URL in the second link now redirects to https://cmake.org/runningcmake/

Answer (score 15):

flutter clean + flutter pub get is the easiest solution

Comment: Perfect! worked for me. I'm using Visual Studio Code

Answer (score 4):

I applied below two command and worked for me.

> flutter clean

> flutter pub get

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same error while running a CGAL code (which I had already compiled sometime ago) . All I did was create a new directory and copy the ".cpp" file there and run " CGAL_create_CMakelists " and then run cmake command.It worked this way. I don't exactly know but I think the error comes when you run the code which was already compiled and has its build files already in the folder(due to previous compiling).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this issue happens when you accidentally mess up with older builds. Removing artefacts of prior/incomplete builds with `rm -r build && rm CMakeCache.txt` etc, should fix the problem.